# How are iPhone device code (Machine IDs) made?

Tags: ios, iphone, cultureinfo

I was wondering how iPhone device code are made ?

```
iPhone1,1 : iPhone
iPhone1,2 : iPhone 3G
iPhone2,1 : iPhone 3GS
iPhone3,1 : iPhone 4
iPhone3,2 : iPhone 4 GSM Rev A
iPhone3,3 : iPhone 4 CDMA
iPhone4,1 : iPhone 4S
iPhone5,1 : iPhone 5 (GSM)
```

Is it just an internal product version number, or maybe there is a techical explanation ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically an internal version number. I don't know if it's documented in public anywhere, but the general format is the product name followed by something like a major and minor version number. In your examples, they're basically "iPhone 1.1", "iPhone 1.2", etc. They don't seem to use 0, so the first version is always a `.1`. The other names in your list are whatever product marketing thinks will sound good.

They do follow major/minor version numbering, like software versioning. The major version goes up by one for each new model, and the minor version indicates variations on the same model. So all the iPhone 4 models in the list have `iPhone3,x`. Why 3? Because "iPhone 4" was a marketing name.

They've used these forever. For example the [PowerBook G4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_G4) line from 20 years ago has the same internal naming convention-- `PowerBook3,2`, `PowerBook3,3`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very instructive :) !